# Good tournaments in 2017 to go for a sport holiday

Tags: tournament

I'm looking for some tournaments that have high tourist (sport) value and are good for spending holiday, played in some sea resort, small town in good place for riding bicycle or somewhere in nature park/mountains to have nice walks. I'm not interested at all in big cities no matter how many museums you can find there and how interesting history does it have. Of course the event should be in time good for desired activity and right in the area of interest, not 10km away. Location preferably close to central europe. Tournament should be strong enough for titled players, may even be GM/IM roundrobins.

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend you the Faaker See Open in Austria,Carinthia.

http://www.faakerseeopen.at/faakersee_open.php#english

It is an lovely area close to a nice lake and mountains nearby.
I have played two times there myself and it is good organized, but if you go there don't book the bed and breakfast place called Pension Wrolich.(It might look cheap but it is not worth it)

Comment: Was swimming in the lake possible at the date of an event or was it already too cold?

Comment: It is possible, most of the time the lake has a temperature of 20-23° in august